# How to run unitest from specific file?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest

In my project I have a task to add few Unittests to APIs.
We have many django apps and I need to do work only with one:

```
apps\data\tests.py
```

But when I'm trying to specify exactly this file/folder to start those exact Tests:

```
python3 manage.py test data.tests
```

or

```
python3 manage.py test data.tests.py
```

its still running ALL tests between ALL apps.
I did make 1 hour search online but Everyone suggesting to use:

```
 python3 manage.py test  + "path to the folder/file".
```

But its still running everything. Maybe i'm missing some General test configuration in settings.py?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start from your `app` name. To run tests only from file `tests.py` in app `apps` run:

```
python3 manage.py test apps.data.tests
```

To run specific `TestCase`, run:

```
python3 manage.py test apps.data.tests.MyTestCase
```

or even only single test:

```
python3 manage.py test apps.data.tests.MyTestCase.my_first_test
```